# How can I fetch a thread including draft messages via the gmail api

Tags: gmail-api

I have a thread in gmail that contains 1 message and 1 draft.

When I use the [api explorer](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/get) to fetch the thread, I get the thread with only one message (the draft is excluded).

Is there a param I can pass in to include the draft in this response?

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/threads/id
```

Comment: Are you sure? I just sent a message to myself and created a draft as a response to it. When I get the thread I get one message with `"labelIds": ["IMPORTANT","SENT","INBOX"]` and one with `"labelIds": ["DRAFT"]`

Comment: Ah, you're right, my issue was that the subject of the draft did not match the subject of the original message, so they didn't thread properly. https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/threads